# Find the sum of $\sum_{i=1}^{5}x^5_i+\sum_{i=1}^{5}\frac{1}{x^5_i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, irreducible-polynomials

> Suppose $x^5+5x^3+1=0$ and $x_i$ denotes all the complex roots. Find the sum of
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{5}x^5_i+\sum_{i=1}^{5}\frac{1}{x^5_i}$$

This polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q[x]$.

I used Vieta's general formulas, however I am not sure if my calculations correct. Here are my calculations.

$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_1x_5+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_2x_5+x_3x_4+x_3x_5+x_4x_5=5$$

$$x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=-1$$

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=0$$

$$x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_2x_5+x_1x_3x_4+x_1x_3x_5+x_1x_4x_5+x_2x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_5+x_2x_4x_5+x_3x_4x_5=0$$

$$x_1x_2x_3x_4+x_1x_2x_3x_5+x_1x_2x_4x_5+x_1x_3x_4x_5+x_2x_3x_4x_5=0$$

This seems so difficult using these formulas. I couldn't make any solution.

How can I simplify this summation?

$$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5+x_4^5+x_5^5$$

I've tried bring the fractions to common denominator and I got

$$\frac {1}{x_1^5}+\frac {1}{x_2^5}+\frac {1}{x_3^5}+\frac {1}{x_4^5}+\frac {1}{x_5^5}=\frac {(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^5+(x_1x_2x_3x_5)^5+(x_1x_2x_4x_5)^5+(x_1x_3x_4x_5)^5+(x_2x_3x_4x_5)^5}{(x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5)^5}=-(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^5-(x_1x_2x_3x_5)^5-(x_1x_2x_4x_5)^5-(x_1x_3x_4x_5)^5-(x_2x_3x_4x_5)^5$$

But, I couldn't make any further progress from here.

Answer (score 14):

Since $x=0$ is not one of the roots of $x^5+5x^3+1=0$, then you can divide all terms of the polynomial by $x^3:$

$$x^2+\frac {1}{x^3}=-5$$

So, why did I do this? Because, we want to construct an *“useful relationship”* between the roots. Then, with a little observation, we want to square both side:

$$x^4+\frac 2x+\frac {1}{x^6}=25$$

Multiplying both side by $x$, we have:

$$x^5+\frac {1}{x^5}=25x-2$$

Finally, we obtain

$$
\begin{align}\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 5}x_i^5+\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 5}\frac {1}{x_i^5}&=\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 5}\left(x_i^5+\frac{1}{x_i^5}\right)\\
&=\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant5}\left(25x_i-2\right)\\
&=25\cdot 0-2\cdot 5\\
&=-10.\end{align}
$$

and you are done.

Comment: Arguments like this bring a smile to my face!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $\ddot\smile$ Thank you very much for checking my answer. I think, we can apply this to the more general quintic $x^5+px^3+1=0$ in the same way. Interestingly, the answer does not depend on the coefficient $p$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^5x_i^k$$ and then we know that $S_1=0$. Next from the given equation we have $$S_5+5S_3+5=0\tag{1}$$ and hence we need to evaluate $S_3$ first. To that end we note that the roots are non-zero and then we can divide the given polynomial equation by $x^2$ to get $$x^3+5x+x^{-2}=0$$ which leads to $$S_3+5S_1+S_{-2}=0$$ ie $S_3=-S_{-2}$. Now $S_{-k} =\sum_{i=1}^5y_i^k$ where $y_i=1/x_i$ are roots of $$1/y^5+5/y^3+1=0$$ ie $$y^5+5y^2+1=0\tag{2}$$ Then we have $$S_{-2}=S_{-1}^2-2\sum y_iy_j=0$$ and thus we get $S_3=0$. Using $(1)$ we get $S_5=-5$.

To evaluate $S_{-5}$ we use equation $(2)$ to get $$S_{-5}+5S_{-2}+5=0$$ and using $S_{-2}=0$ we get $S_{-5}=-5$ and thus $S_{5}+S_{-5}=-10$.

Comment: Isn't that $S_n$ method only works for $n\in\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @An_Elephant: well if none of the roots are zero (ie polynomial has a non-zero constant term) then it works for $n\in\mathbb{Z} $ as well.

Comment: Thanks sir. In my classes , I was told a limited version of it.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$x^5 = -5x^3-1$$
and as t all roots are not $0$, the initial equation is equivalent to
$$1+5\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^5}=0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{x^5} = -\frac{5}{x^2}-1$$
Then, the sum is equal to
$$L:=-10-5\sum_{i=1}^5(x^3+\frac{1}{x^2})=-10-5\left(\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}^3+\sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{1}{x_{\sigma(1)}^2}\right)$$

---

For the first term $\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}^3$, using the Vieta's formula, we have:
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)} &= 0 \\
&\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)} &= 5\\
&\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}x_{\sigma(3)} &= 0\\
\end{align}$$

We have from [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=SymmetricReduction%5Bx%5E3%20%2B%20y%5E3%20%2B%20z%5E3%20%2B%20u%5E3%20%2B%20w%5E3%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20y%2C%20z%2C%20u%2C%20w%7D%5D)   (normally, a real mathematician needs to know this formula by heart ;) )
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}^3&=\left(\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}  \right)^3 - 3\left(\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}\right)\left(\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)} \right)+3\left(\sum_{\text{sym}}x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}x_{\sigma(3)}  \right)\\
& = 0^3 -3\cdot0\cdot5+3\cdot 0 \\
&= 0  \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

---

For the second term $\sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{1}{x_{\sigma(1)}^2}$, we remark that these $\frac{1}{x}$ are the roots of the equation
$$1 + 5y^2 + y^5 = 0 \tag{2}$$
Let denote $y_i$ the roots of $(2)$, we have $\sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{1}{x_{\sigma(1)}^2} = \sum_{\text{sym}}y_{\sigma(1)}^2$. By the same method, using the Vieta's formula, we have:
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{\text{sym}}y_{\sigma(1)} &= 0 \\
&\sum_{\text{sym}}y_{\sigma(1)}y_{\sigma(2)} &= 0\\
\end{align}$$

and from [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=SymmetricReduction%5Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20%2B%20u%5E2%20%2B%20w%5E2%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20y%2C%20z%2C%20u%2C%20w%7D%5D), we have
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{\text{sym}}y_{\sigma(1)}^2&=\left(\sum_{\text{sym}}y_{\sigma(1)}  \right)^2 - 2\left(\sum_{\text{sym}}y_{\sigma(1)}y_{\sigma(2)} \right)\\
& = 0^2 -2\cdot 0 \\
&= 0  \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

---

So, we can compute $L$ from $(1)$ and $(3)$
$$\color{red}{L} = -10 -5 \left( 0 + 0   \right) \color{red}{= -10}$$

Comment: @user1094359 The right answer must be $-10$

Answer (score 2):

if you have a polinomial of any degree, e.g $p(x)=ax^5+bx^3+c$, with roots $r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_5$, lets denote $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{5}r_i^k = r_1^k+r_2^k+\cdots+r_5^k$.2

This is a fact well known. But the additional information of this answer is that for any $k\in\mathbb{C}$ is true that:
$$aS_{K+5}+bS_{K+3}+cS_K=0$$

So, if you known $S_0, S_1, S_2...$ you can use it to known the rest of the values that you require. For example: $aS_5 +bS_3 + cS_1 = 0$ in the example showed.

Also, you can have in a easy manner the values of $S_{-1}, S_{-2}, S_{-3}, \cdots$

you have to make a "**non-algebraic division**$^1$" $p'(x)/p(x)$ with Horner-Method and the coefficients will be the values of $S_0, S_{-1}, S_{-2}, S_{-3}, ...$.

For example. for your polinomial in the example: (if anyone can edit on latex would be better)

[image]

Note that this method works for any polinomial and any value of $k$

Answer (score 2):

According to **Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials**,
symmetric polynomials can expressed as polynomial of elementary symmetric polynomials, i.e. the LHS of Vieta's formula.

Then by using math software, the calculation is as follow.
The result of $\sum_{i=1}^{5} x_i^5$ is
$$
s_{1}^{5} - 5 s_{1}^{3} s_{2} + 5 s_{1}^{2} s_{3} + 5 s_{1} s_{2}^{2} - 5 s_{1} s_{4} - 5 s_{2} s_{3} + 5 s_{5}$$

The result of $\sum_{i=1}^{5} \frac{1}{x_i^5}$ is
$$ \frac{- 5 s_{1} s_{4} s_{5}^{3} - 5 s_{2} s_{3} s_{5}^{3} + 5 s_{2} s_{4}^{2} s_{5}^{2} + 5 s_{3}^{2} s_{4} s_{5}^{2} - 5 s_{3} s_{4}^{3} s_{5} + s_{4}^{5} + 5 s_{5}^{4}}{s_{5}^{5}}$$

Given the equation $x^5+5x^3+1=0$,
$s_1=0,s_2=5,s_3=0,s_4=0,s_5=-1$.
Hence the final result is $-10$.